# Check browser's mouse lock permission before requesting

Tags: javascript

I just want to access whether I have permission to lock the user's cursor without sending a requestPointerLock().

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen for [`pointerlockerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerlockerror) when requesting for `requestPointerLock()`. That way you will know if user browser can lock your pointer

Comment: But if I request it and pointer locking is allowed, then I will lock the pointer. I ONLY want to know whether it's allowed. I don't want to lock it.

Comment: @EricMarchettiSantos If it succeeded then use `exitPointerLock` immediately after lock. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitPointerLock

Comment: Doing so will translate the cursor to the element requested. That is not ideal.
Also, if the browser has to explicitly ask the user for permission, then it is a bit worse.

Comment: @EricMarchettiSantos Asking for permission if that permission exists is not bad thing.